# vedic texts about the art of dancing or art in general

Tags: scripture, book-recommendation

Are there any vedic texts that describe/teach the art of dancing? If not is there a vedic text that describe the dance of lord Nataraj?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, we have the various Upavedas associated with the four Vedas. Dhanurveda, Ayurveda, Gandharvaveda etc.

> There are four Upavedas: Dhanurveda, Gandharvaveda, Ayurveda and
>   Arthasastra. Some schools hold Sthapatyaveda as the fourth Upaveda
>   instead of Arthasastra.
>
> Dhanurveda is the science of warfare.  **Gandharvaveda is the study
>   if aesthetics and it speaks of all art-forms like music, dance,
>   poetry, sculpture, and erotica.** Ayurveda is the science of health
>   and life. Arthasastra deals with public administration, governance,
>   economy and polity. Sthapatyaveda relates with engineering and
>   Architecture.
>
> All these sciences/arts are discussed not just from their technical
>   perspective (though that is primarily done), but also as a means to
>   transcendence.
>
> [Source-Hindupedia](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Upaveda).

Therefore, Gandharvaveda is the scripture you are looking for.

Each of these Upavedas are related to one Veda or the other. Gandharvaveda is related to the Samaveda.

> Gandharva veda, the upaveda of the "Sama Veda," is the study of all
>   art forms including music, dance and poetry. This Vedic text contains
>   information about the laws and ways to practice music as well as how
>   music works as a therapy to heal the body and soul. Gandharva veda
>   uses the music of nature to restore balance of body and mind.
>
> Gandharva veda also offers a detailed account on the the association
>   of music with various aspects of creation and the positive impact of
>   music on the body and mind. It also gives insight on the association
>   of different sounds and rhythms with different species on Earth.
>
> Gandharva veda is effectively used in meditation as it helps the yogi
>   transcend to the innermost level of the mind.
>
> [Source-Yogapedia.](https://www.yogapedia.com/definition/5560/gandharva-veda)

[This page](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/gandharvaveda) lists some instances where the term Gandharvaveda is found in various Hindu scriptures.

> The Shiva Purana (by J. L. Shastri)
>
> Chapter 1 - Origin of the sacred lore < [Section 7.1 -
>   Vāyavīya-saṃhitā (1)]
>
> There are eighteen secular Vidyās—Āyurveda Dhanurveda, Gāndharvaveda
>   etc. ending with Arthaśāstra. 27

> The Mahabharata - Third Book (by Krishna-Dwaipayana Vyasa)
>
> Section XCI < [Tirtha-yatra Parva]
>
> And having thus acquired weapons and mastered the Gandharva Veda, thy
>   third brother Vibhatsu liveth happily

> The Brahmanda Purana (by G.V. Tagare)
>
> Chapter 35 - The legend of Yājñavalkya’s receiving the Veda from the
>   Sun-God < [Section 2 - Anuṣaṅga-pāda]
>
> The Āyurveda (Science of medicine) The Yajurveda The Dhanurveda
>   (Military Science) The Sāmaveda The Gāndharvaveda

[Vedicreserve](https://vedicreserve.miu.edu/gandharva_veda.htm) gives the names of the two texts that are dedicated on this particular Upaveda.

- Natya Shastra ([PDF](https://vedicreserve.miu.edu/gandharva_veda/natya_shastra.pdf))
- [Sangita Ratnakara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sangita_Ratnakara) ([PDF](https://vedicreserve.miu.edu/gandharva_veda/samgita_ratnakara_1_to_7.pdf))

Natya Shastra (translated into English) can be bought from [here](https://www.amazon.in/Natyashastra-Introduction-English-Translation-Indices/dp/8183152449?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&psc=1) too.